# Red Hat 7.5 yum reposync error

Tags: redhat, yum, repository, reposync

I am trying to updating my packages by using the command, reposync which download from the RHN (Red Hat Network). So I create a local mirror of the latest update for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5,  7.5. Here is the link, https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23016
 I set up the local repo using the iso file.

This is my local.repo

```
[LocalRepo]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5
baseurl=file://mnt
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Here is the yum repolist output

```
repo id    repo name                  status

LocalRepo  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5 5099
```

I set up the required package

```
 yum install yum-utils createrepo
```

Then I used the command

```
 reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=LocalRepo --download_path=/var/yvmdi
```

and even this command

```
 reposync  --repoid=LocalRepo --download_path=/var/yvmdi
```

The result failed as the result shows all the rpm package failed and also states multiples times no more mirrors to try.

### Rpm package failed

[image: Rpm package failed]

### No more mirrors to try

[image: No more mirrors to try]

The reason why I am doing this is that some of the package require the latest patch thus, I use reposync to get new updates from Red Hat Network.
Can you kindly assist this problem? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to not directly answering your question, but given what you want to do, I'm positive that you will be happier with [Foreman](https://www.theforeman.org) (or RHEL Satellite Server, if you want to buy the product) - it takes care of inventory, *mirroring packages* from Redhat and other repos, *releasing* and *overriding* package versions to your environment, hosting you own package repos, handling bare-metal and VM provisioning, proxying licensing for RHEL.

Plus, it's useful as a Puppet master and ENC.

I used to mess with mrepo when RHN was still a thing, but having Foreman, I never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but for others with the same problem use sudo when running almost anything yum related, including reposync.

```
sudo reposync --gpgcheck -l --repoid=LocalRepo --download_path=/var/yvmdi
```

Comment: Would a failure to run `reposync` without root privileges produce the error output provided in the question, though?

Comment: It did for me. In my experience yum does not provide great errors when run without proper permissions.

Comment: I am already running reposync as root and still encountering the `FAILED` and `No more mirrors to try` messages.

Answer (score 0):

clear cache or delete yum cache directory every time you run reposync

Comment: Can you provide commands or a reference on how to do this? I tried `yum clean all` and that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found this article (https://bgstack15.wordpress.com/2019/05/05/reposync-fails-no-more-mirrors-to-try/) which suggested deleting some of the affected files in the repo.

So I removed the files (`rm -f openscap*`) in the 'updates' Packages directory (13 removed) and on the next sync I got no errors for those packages (13 downloaded).

Repeat for any remaining errors and Bob's your uncle.